# In python: missing randomness (fractional Brownian motion)

Tags: python, random, matplotlib, fractals, seed

I am new to Python. I have two scripts for generating and plotting a 2D lattice which values represent a spatially distributed attribute in the form of a fractal image. The first script contains the **function** generating the fractal (orthodox name: *Spectral Synthesis with Inverse Fourier Transform*), while the second simply calls the function, plots it, ad writes it to a .csv file. The **function** relies on multiple `random.gauss(0.0, sigma)` calls for obtaining normally distributed random numbers. It also calls `random.random()` since it needs other random numbers. *Below are the codes*. **Thanks to anyone who will help!**

**The problem**: the plot always shows the same pattern, hence making me think that there is something NOT random in the code. My intention is to obtain a different fractal image every time I run the code. What makes it NOT random? Is that `seed=122` in the second script?
**PS**: please note that since the procedure introduces a given degree of periodicity, and since I do not want that periodicity to be shown, the plotted lattice is smaller than the generated lattice. In particular, I am using *size(plotted)=101x101*, while *size(generated)=256x256*.

**First script: the function itself**

```
from __future__ import division #Avoids the floor of the mathematical result of division if the args are ints or longs
import numpy
import random
import math
import pylab

def SpectralSynthesisFM2D(max_level, sigma, H, seed=0, normalise=True, bounds=[0,1]):
  """
  ________________________________________________________________________
  Args:
      max_level : Maximum number of recursions (N = 2^max_level)
      sigma     : Initial standard deviation
      H         : Roughness constant (Hurst exponent), varies form 0.0 to 1.0
      H=0.8 is a good representation of many natural phenomena (Voss, 1985)
      seed      : seed value for random number generator
      normalise : normalizes the data using bound
      bounds    : used for normalization of the grid data
  Result:     
      Output is given in the form of an array (grid) which holds surface
      values for a square region.  
  _________________________________________________________________________
  """   

  N = int(2**max_level)
  A = numpy.zeros((N,N), dtype = complex)
  random.seed() #Seeds the random number generator
  PI = 3.141592
  for i in range(0,int((N-1)/2)):
    for j in range(0,int((N-1)/2)):
      phase = 2*PI*random.random() #/random.randrange(1,Arand)
      if i != 0 or j != 0:
        rad = pow((i*i + j*j),(-(H+1)/2) )*random.gauss(0.0, sigma)
      else:
        rad = 0.0

      A[i][j] = rad*math.cos(phase) + rad*math.sin(phase)*j 

      if i ==0: 
        i0 = 0
      else:
        i0 = N - i

      if j==0:
        j0 = 0
      else:
        j0 = N - j

      A[i0][j0] = rad * math.cos(phase) - rad*math.sin(phase)*j

  for i in range(1,int((N-1)/2)):
    for j in range(1,int((N-1)/2)):
      phase = 2*PI*random.random() #/random.randrange(1,Arand)
      rad = pow((i*i + j*j),(-(H+1)/2) )*random.gauss(0.0, sigma)
      A[i][N-j] = rad * math.cos(phase) + rad* math.sin(phase)*j
      A[N-i][j] = rad * math.cos(phase) - rad* math.sin(phase)*j

  Grid = numpy.real(pylab.ifft2(( A ))) #Implements the Discrete Inverse Fast Fourier Transform on a 2D lattice (grid)
  if(normalise):
        Grid += numpy.amin(Grid)*-1 + bounds[0]
        Grid = (Grid/numpy.amax(Grid)) * bounds[1]
  return Grid
```

**Second script: plotting the function and obtaining the fractal image:**

```
from __future__ import division #Avoids the floor of the mathematical result of division if the args are ints or longs
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mc
import SSFM2D 


#Parameter assignments
max_level=8               #This is the exponent controlling the grid size. In this case N=2^8=256. Use only integers.
N=2**max_level
sigma=1                   #Variation for random Gauss generation (standardised normal distribution)
H=0.8                     #Hurst exponent (0.8 is a recommended value for natural phenomena)
seed=122                    #Setting the seed for random Gauss generation
print ('The lattice size is '+str(N)+'x'+str(N))


#Lattice initialization
Lattice=np.zeros((256,256))


#Calling Spectral fBm function
Lattice=SSFM2D.SpectralSynthesisFM2D(max_level, sigma, H, seed, normalise=True, bounds=[0,1])


#Plotting the lattice
M=np.zeros((101,101))     #Lattice to be plotted. Size(M) != size(Lattice) to minimize visual fBm periodic features. 
for i in range(0,101):
    for j in range(0,101):
        M[i][j]=Lattice[i][j]


#Lattice statistics              
print M[-101:,-101:].sum()
print M[-101:,-101:].max()
print M[-101:,-101:].min()
print M[-101:,-101:].mean()        


#Writing X, Y and values to a .csv file from scratch
import numpy
import csv
with open('C:\\Users\\Francesco\\Desktop\\Python_files\\csv\\fBm_256x256.csv', 'w') as f: # Change directory if necessary
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['X', 'Y', 'Value'])
    for (x, y), val in numpy.ndenumerate(M):
        writer.writerow([x, y, val])

# Plotting - Showing interpolation of randomization
plt.imshow(M[-101:,-101:].T, origin='lower',interpolation='nearest',cmap='Blues', norm=mc.Normalize(vmin=0,vmax=M.max()))
title_string=('fBm: Inverse FFT on Spectral Synthesis')
subtitle_string=('Lattice size: 101x101')
plt.suptitle(title_string, y=0.99, fontsize=17)
plt.title(subtitle_string, fontsize=9)
plt.show()

# Makes a custom list of tick mark intervals for colour bar (assumes minimum is always zero)
numberOfTicks = 5
ticksListIncrement = M.max()/(numberOfTicks)
ticksList = []
for i in range((numberOfTicks+1)):
    ticksList.append(ticksListIncrement * i) 

cb=plt.colorbar(orientation='horizontal', format='%0.2f', ticks=ticksList) 
cb.set_label('Values') 
plt.show()
plt.xlim(0, 100)
plt.xlabel('Easting (Cells)') 
plt.ylim(100, 0)
plt.ylabel('Northing (Cells)')
```

Comment: If you want it to be different each time, why are you using a `seed`?! Have you read the docs for the methods you're using, to find out what their parameters are for?

Comment: i have no idea what `SpectralSynthesisFM2D` does and how it uses the `seed` variable. why don't you try to use `seed = random.randint(?,?)` and check if the results are still identical? (replace the `?` with the values that are acceptable as seed for this function).

Comment: In a few words `SpectralSynthesisFM2D` produces a fractal matrix, which is later plotted. It uses the `seed` variable to pick random numbers to produce the "random" polar coordinates used in this version of the Inverse Fourier Transform. I suspect this randomness isn't really implemented, thus I keep seeing the same image. But I fail to locate the bug...

Comment: (Seeing your comment in the answer below..) To delete your own question [some conditions need to be met](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) (e.g. you would have to unaccept the answer before you delete your question). If the answer below solved your problem, then you shouldn't delete your question. If you found an answer to your problem (and you consider it to be use for future viewers) then you should post it, and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usually a `seed` is used to initialize a random number generator. same `seed` -> same sequence of random numbers (which is very userful for testing).

```
import random

random.seed(22)

for i in range(10):
    print(random.randint(0, 100))
```

so no matter how many times you run that program (or even on what machine), the output will always be the same.

but when you want 'real' randomness (or at least better randomness) you better call

```
random.seed()  # or: random.seed(None)
```

with no arguments. python then calls [`seed`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.seed) using the current system time - which provides a source of some randomness.

as i do not know your library i can't tell for sure but i'd bet it works in a simliar way. you could try to set `seed=None` or `seed=random.randint(something)`.

in any case: be sure to read the api documentation of your library and check what `seed` does.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me through. I anyhow made it to obtain what I wanted. I run Python with Canopy: I simply rebooted the Kernel, which had accumulated a good degree of garbage, and now the randomness is back. How can we close this question?